# Color cell where radio button is located and selected but not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to color a table cell during the `$(document).ready(function(){` load process by checking if a hidden radio button is selected.  If it is, I need the table cell to highlight.

I have the following code:

```
if($('#q1c').is(':checked')) { 
    $(this).effect("highlight", {color: 'green'}, 1000);
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```

But this does not work as it doesn't refer to the table cell that the radio button resides in, it's using `this` which is incorrect.

The code below works as it's based on an `on click` event:

```
$('#rq1').on('click', 'td', function() {
   $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
   $('.q1').removeClass("selected");
   $(this).effect("highlight", {color: 'green'}, 1000);
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing but to highlight the cell when the page loads and the radio button is pre-selected.

**JS Fiddle**:

Using feedback from below, have tried implemting the following but no joy.

https://jsfiddle.net/hryxge5n/1/

I'm wondering if `closest` is correct - I'm struggling to get my head around whether the radio button and table cell have a relationship that would allow `closest` to work?

Comment: Are those `radio` buttons created at runtime on page load?

Comment: They are created via the .PHP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you apply effect to checkbox, while you should apply it to table cell. Try doing it this way. You find checkbox and then apply effect to the TD in which checkbox is located.

```
if($('#q1c').is(':checked')) { 
    $(this).closest('td').effect("highlight", {color: 'green'}, 1000);
    $(this).closest('td').addClass("selected");
}
```

**Edit**:

`this` can't be used here as it refers to the `window` and there is no closest.  Changed for the `id` of which you need the closest element.

```
if ($('#q1c').prop('checked')) {
    $('#q1c').closest('td').effect("highlight", {color: 'green'}, 1000);
    $('#q1c').closest('td').addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, learnt something new!  Alas however, this isn't working.  When the page is loading it's not highlighting nor adding the class.  No error messages.

Comment: `<td class="tg-031e eq q1" ><input class="hidden" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" type="radio" checked="" onclick="mand();">c</td>` - this is the code I have for the input radio button.

Comment: Did you check with debugger? Is the code inside `if` executed? Try using .prop('checked') instead of is(':checked').

Comment: I've been playing - so, I put an `alert` in and that fires fine - `$(this).closest('td').addClass("selected");` doesn't - is it to do with parent/ child - is the radio button a child of the `td`?